# RecordRTC recording cancel

Tags: angular, recordrtc

Currently we have options to Start and Stop the recording using RecordRTC in an angular project.
But Please help how can I add Cancel option to be able to start recording again?

These are for start and cancel recording-
//start recording...

```
 async startRecording() {
   if (this.stream == null && this.recorder == null) {
    try {
      this.stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
       });

       navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true})
       .then(stream => {
         this.recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
           mimeType: 'video/webm'
        });
        this.recorder.startRecording();
        this.video.srcObject = stream;
        this.video.muted = true;
        this.video.autoplay = true;
      })
      .catch(ex => {
      });
   } catch (ex) {
     this.errorMessage = true;
     }
   }
  }
//stop recording...
stopRecording() {
 this.video.srcObject = null;
 this.video.muted = false;
 this.video.autoplay = false;

 if (this.stream != null && this.recorder != null) {
    this.recorder.stopRecording(url => {
      this.video.src = url;
    });
   this.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`destroy()`](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/blob/ebae1da10f50a521000cbcced5c5adfb96f32411/RecordRTC.js#L753) to clean everything. In your case:

```
this.recorder.stopRecording(url => {
   this.video.src = url;
   this.recorder.destroy();
   this.recorder = null;
});
```